# Using the contents of cell's as part of a file location in a macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

This is what I have:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub EditWorksheet()
Workbooks.Open "Y:\Laurence\contents(J2)"
Sheets("contents(N2)").Select

End Sub
```

So what I want to do is have VBA call on the values of cells J2 and N2 in order to decide which workbook and worksheet to open. For your information J2 could contain for example "Forecast2016.xlsx" and N2 may contain "MASTER". Just to be clear, for every possible content these cells can have, I do indeed have a spreadsheet in the relevant file location (Y:\Laurence).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change `"Y:\Laurence\contents(J2)"` to `"Y:\Laurence\" & Range("J2")`

Comment: Thanks for that quick reply. And do you have a similar replacement for the sheet part? i.e. Sheets("contents(N2)").Select

Comment: `Sheets(Range("N2")).Select`, you should have figured it out yourself :)

Comment: I did actually try that but unfortunately it came back with an error. Run time error 13 type mismatch. I am a bit of a novice as you can probably tell... so I hope you don't mind me asking if you have a diagnosis?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not passing a string, but a range with that code. This causes the run time error 13. Instead of

```
Workbooks.Open "Y:\Laurence\contents(J2)"
Sheets("contents(N2)").Select
```

try

```
Workbooks.Open "Y:\Laurence\" & Sheets("Contents").Range("N2").Value
Sheets(Sheets("Contents").Range("N2").Value).Select
```

This forces the value of the cell to be passed, not a reference to the range. Also notice I qualified your worksheet that you were referencing as well. As you had it before, it would have pulled Range("N2") from whatever sheet happened to be open at that moment.